# Get Function memory address

Tags: winapi, memory

I have foo.exe which is using some of Windows API functions. I want to get memory addresses of those functions, how do I do that? Any software available which I can use?

Note, that I am looking for non-programatically way of doing that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking for non-programatically way of doing that.

Either this is not possible or it doesn't make any sense. Likely both.

You see, in order to call one of the Windows API functions, a program must import it from the DLL that contains the function of interest. This requires that DLL to be loaded into the address space of that program's process. And because each process has its own address space, each process gets its own unique instance (or copy) of the DLL. That means that the "memory address" of functions provided by DLLs is going to be different in each process.

Retrieving this information non-programmatically just doesn't make sense. Even if you *could* get it, it wouldn't do you any good.

I could probably provide better advice if you edited your question to explain what you're hoping to *accomplish*, rather than just asking about the approach you already settled upon.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I am studying Win Hooks, and in one of the tutorials guy using static MessageBox address to write into it his custom function.

I understand that this address should change every time, but in order to get some practice it might be useful to know how I can get it manually. Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of any way that is going to work... Do you have a link to the tutorial? Perhaps it's suggesting that you do something else and you're misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 2):

The addresses of exported functions can be different for every process that loads the DLL. The `GetProcAddress` function can tell you what they are for your process.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I am looking for non-programatically way of getting memory address.

Comment: @BillGates: Did you fully read Jonathan's answer?  The "memory address" you get will be meaningless for anything but the program that's calling `GetProcAddress`.  It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here.